# Adding on to inherited initialization?

Tags: python

Let's say I have some code that creates a class:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, param1):
        do something with param1
```

now let's say I have an object, ItemChild, that inherits from that class and inherits its initialization function, i.e., has some code that calls Item's `__init__` function. However, let's say I also want it to do more in its `__init__` function, and I want it to work with more parameters, i.e., param1, param2, param3, and param4. It seems like the call to the parent's `__init__` function will now be confused, since it won't know which parameter is param1 when I pass params 1-3 into an instance of ItemChild. Is there any way to get around this, or is inheritance of the initialization method limited to that method and cannot be extended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the proper way to handle a scenario like this:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, param1):
        # do something with param1

class ItemChild(Item):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3, param4):
        super(ItemChild, self).__init__(param1)
        # do something with params
```

Note that `Item` inheriting from `object` is important because [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) only works with new-style classes.

As noted in comments, with 3.x you do not need to include the arguments to `super()`, you can just use `super().__init__(param1)`.

Comment: Note in 3.x, you can use the new `super()`, which does some magic and doesn't need arguments.

Answer (score 3):

It will actually work the other way around - `ItemChild`'s `__init__` method will be called first, and can forward on only what is appropriate to `Item`:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, param1):
        print "Item.__init__ doing something with param1"
        # do something with param1


class ItemChild(Item):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3):
        print "Starting ItemChild.__init__"
        super(ItemChild, self).__init__(param1)
        print "ItemChild.__init__ doing something with params 2 and 3"
        # do something with param2 and param3
```

When you call `ItemChild(1, 2, 3)` the flow is as follows:

```
Starting ItemChild.__init__
Item.__init__ doing something with param1
ItemChild.__init__ doing something with params 2 and 3
```

not:

```
Item.__init__ doing something with param1
Starting ItemChild.__init__
ItemChild.__init__ doing something with params 2 and 3
```

Of course, you could re-arrange your `super` call so it runs before or after you do other things - or you can leave it out entirely if you don't want to have the parent's behavior run.

Answer (score 2):

No, just delegate the arguments in the child's `__init__` as you need.

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, w, x, y, z):
        Parent.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.w = w
        self.z = z

p = Parent(1, 2)
# p.x == 1
# p.y == 2
c = Child(1, 2, 3, 4)
# c.w = 1
# c.x = 2
# c.y = 3
# c.z = 4
```

You can also use `super` as mentioned in the other examples.  For most cases, it's mainly a matter of personal preference, but when you start designing more advanced classes, the difference becomes important.  `super` will look for the `__init__()` methods of a class' parents in MRO order, calling the cooperatively when warranted.  Directly calling the superclass' `__init__()` method sacrifices some automatic functionality for explicit control.  Also, with `super`, you have to be careful that all `__init__()` methods that a child will discover have compatible signatures, otherwise you will get exceptions.